# How to take 10 digit phone number from database in android app correctly

Tags: android

If I am taking 9 digit number in android app is showing correct but if I change number to 10 digits a random number is generated?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: ok, than you have error in your code. Good luck fixing it on your own. Sorry, can't use telepathy to see where is the problem.

Comment: Sir, I have used varchar(100) as datatype to store phone numbers.   When I take phone number 945143198 9 digit it show it correctly and when i take it 9451431987 10 digit automatically it give me a random number. and that number is different for every different phone number

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is hard to know, but my guess is you are storing the phone number in a 32 bit int. After 2147483647 this will overflow and your results appear random. You could test by trying a phone number like 1111111111 and seeing if that works.

Comment: I don't think that *trying to guess* such an unclear problem to give a solution has good impact on StackOverflow structure and community. I'd clarify the question first before answering.

Comment: @VladMatvienko You can call it a guess. I call it a strong hypothesis based on many years of experience and supported by all available facts ;-) If OP clarifies the question and I'm wrong, I'll happily delete the answer.

Comment: Sir, I have used varchar(100) as datatype to store phone numbers.   When I take phone number 945143198 9 digit it show it correctly and when i take it 9451431987 10 digit automatically it give me a random number. and that number is different for every different phone number

Comment: @VipinDhonkaria You need to edit your question to show how you are trying to get your data out of the DB and display it.